# Converting week date into calendar date

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have column with dates in format:

```
year/number_of_week_in_year/number_of_day_of_the_week, for example:

2015015 = 01.01.2015
```

How to write query which convert this date to RRRRmmdd format?

I use Oracle 10g.

Comment: You mean 1-4 char are year, 5-6 are number of weeks, 7th char is day in week. So how would 23.08.2015 be shown in your column? Add some more example and the output format. 01.01.2015 can we DD.MM or MM.DD.

Comment: I think this is what you need - https://community.oracle.com/thread/300823?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: @Utsav if the input is in ISO standard then `23.08.2015` would be `2015/34/7` which can be converted by `TO_CHAR( DATE '2015-08-23', 'IYYY/IW/' ) || (DATE '2015-08-23' - TRUNC( DATE '2015-08-23', 'IW' ) + 1) ` - however, the reverse conversion is trickier as it is not possible to do using `TO_DATE` as you get an `ORA-01820` error.

Comment: What format is your input in? If you use the ISO standard for weeks then `2015015` (day 5 of the 1st ISO week of 2015) is `2nd January 2015`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the ISO standard for weeks then you can do:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c05cb/7)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE FUNCTION TO_ISO_WEEK_DATE(
  year      NUMBER,
  week      NUMBER,
  dayofweek NUMBER DEFAULT 1
) RETURN DATE DETERMINISTIC
IS
BEGIN
  RETURN NEXT_DAY(
          TO_DATE( TO_CHAR( year, '0000' ) || '0104', 'YYYYMMDD' )
            - INTERVAL '7' DAY, 'MONDAY'
         )
         + ( week - 1 ) * 7
         + ( dayofweek - 1 );
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    RETURN NULL;
END TO_ISO_WEEK_DATE;
/
```

**Query 1**:

```
WITH dates (value ) AS (
  SELECT DATE '2015-01-01' + LEVEL - 1
  FROM   DUAL
  CONNECT BY LEVEL < 366
),
data ( value, iso_week_day ) AS (
  SELECT value,
         TO_CHAR( value, 'IYYY/IW/' ) || TO_CHAR( value - TRUNC( value, 'IW' ) + 1 )
  FROM   dates
)
SELECT value,
       iso_week_day,
       TO_ISO_WEEK_DATE(
         SUBSTR( iso_week_day, 1, 4 ),
         SUBSTR( iso_week_day, 6, 2 ),
         SUBSTR( iso_week_day, 9, 1 )
       ) AS CONVERTED_DATE
FROM data
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c05cb/7/0)**:

```
|                       VALUE | ISO_WEEK_DAY |              CONVERTED_DATE |
|-----------------------------|--------------|-----------------------------|
|   January, 01 2015 00:00:00 |    2015/01/4 |   January, 01 2015 00:00:00 |
|   January, 02 2015 00:00:00 |    2015/01/5 |   January, 02 2015 00:00:00 |
|   January, 03 2015 00:00:00 |    2015/01/6 |   January, 03 2015 00:00:00 |
|   January, 04 2015 00:00:00 |    2015/01/7 |   January, 04 2015 00:00:00 |
|   January, 05 2015 00:00:00 |    2015/02/1 |   January, 05 2015 00:00:00 |
   ...
|    August, 23 2015 00:00:00 |    2015/34/7 |    August, 23 2015 00:00:00 |
   ...
|  December, 30 2015 00:00:00 |    2015/53/3 |  December, 30 2015 00:00:00 |
|  December, 31 2015 00:00:00 |    2015/53/4 |  December, 31 2015 00:00:00 |
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right, this is what you want:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(NEXT_DAY(
NEXT_DAY( to_date('01.01.'||SUBSTR('2015015',1,4),'dd.mm.yyyy')-7,1) +      
(SUBSTR('2015015',5,2)-1)*7,TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR('2015015',7,1))),'rrrrmmdd')
FROM dual;
```

Comment: There is something wrong as `2015011` outputs `20150105` and `2015015` outputs `20150102` (which is an earlier date even though the input is a later date).

Answer (score 1):

In case you're trying to reverse Oracle's `yyyywwd` format mask, the code below might be of use. However - it is not universal and depends on your NLS settings (names for days and which day is considered first day of week SUN/MON).

It is strange though, that `to_date()` does not accept `'ww'` as a format.

```
select dt,
       dt_ywd,
       next_day(to_date(substr(dt_ywd,1,4)||'0101','yyyymmdd') +
                  7*(to_number(substr(dt_ywd,5,2))-1) -
                  1,
                decode(substr(dt_ywd,7,1),'1','SUN',
                                          '2','MON',
                                          '3','TUE',
                                          '4','WED',
                                          '5','THU',
                                          '6','FRI',
                                          '7','SAT')) tst_revert
  from(select dt, 
              to_char(dt,'yyyywwd') dt_ywd
         from (select to_date('01/01/2015','dd/mm/yyyy')+level-1 dt
                 from dual
              connect by level < 500))
```

This gives me the following output:

```
DT          DT_YWD  TST_REVERT
----------- ------- -----------
01/01/2015  2015015 01/01/2015
02/01/2015  2015016 02/01/2015
03/01/2015  2015017 03/01/2015
04/01/2015  2015011 04/01/2015
05/01/2015  2015012 05/01/2015
06/01/2015  2015013 06/01/2015
07/01/2015  2015014 07/01/2015
08/01/2015  2015025 08/01/2015
09/01/2015  2015026 09/01/2015
10/01/2015  2015027 10/01/2015
```